# Where should I keep selection state for a list?

Tags: list, ember.js, multi-select

I'm using ember 1.0.0-pre4.

I want to display a list of Model instances. The user should be able to select as many list entries by clicking a button or checkbox that is rendered within each row.

I managed to display the list. But I don't know how to manage selection state. When I put something like `{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="isSelected"}}` into the template then the selection state will be held in my model. But I don't think this is the best place. I think selection state belongs to the controller or view state.

Could you please tell me the best way to store and access (multiple) list selection state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to just keep a second list in the controller:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  selectedContent: [],
  selectToggle: function(event) {
    var selectedContent;
    selectedContent = this.get(selectedContent);
    if (selectedContent.contains(event.context)) {
      return this.set('selectedContent', selectedContent.without(event.context));
    } else {
      return this.get('selectedContent').push(event.context);
    }
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each foo in controller}}
          <li {{action selectToggle foo}}>{{foo.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

That just maintains a separate list in the controller and pushes/removes based on whether or not the item was selected.

You could also use an Ember.ObjectProxy to augment the values of the foo object with an "isSelected" property.

```
App.FooController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  selectedContent: @get('content').map(function(item){
    Ember.ObjectProxy.create({ 
      content: item
      isSelected: false
    });
  }); 
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each foo in controller.selectedContent}}
          <li {{bindAttr class= "foo.isSelected"}}{{action selectToggle foo}}>{{foo.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Then in your selectToggle method you just set foo's isSelected property appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andre. I will try that today. Could you please also tell me how the solution would look like with Ember.ArrayProxy? I want to know all possibilities in Ember to be able to choose the right solution for this and maybe future problems.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can access the selectedContent list from the template, for example to render the selected rows with a different style?

Comment: Do do that you need to use the ObjectProxy method. I've updated the answer.