# How to highlight selected address?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

If the user clicks the `li` entry, it triggers the `useThisAddress` action, which sets `isSelected` in the `address` object to `true`. From there `bind-attr` takes care of setting the appropriate class (ie `border-black').

Is this the right way to go about this? Or is there a better approach?

Below code works. However, I am a bit uncertain about setting `isSelected` to `true` on the `address` object, since it isn't a real property in the `address` object model.

```
// Controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  active: null,

  actions: {
    useThisAddress: function(address) {
      address.set('isSelected', true);
      var active = this.get('active');
      if (active) {
        active.set('isSelected', false);
      }
      this.set('active', address);
    }
  }
})

// Template
<ul>
  {{#each address in model}}
    <li {{bind-attr class='address.isSelected:border-black'}} {{action 'useThisAddress' address}}>
      Address: {{address.address1}} {{address.address2}}, {{address.city}}, {{address.postalCode}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your gut reaction is correct - you shouldn't be setting properties on your models that are strictly related to your UI.

Components are the building blocks in Ember for storing UI-layer state. It's a somewhat tricky time in Ember, because Controllers are also used for this purpose, but they're on the way out. Soon it will be all components.

When I encounter a case like yours (list-with-selected-items), I usually make a `list` component and a `list-item` component. The `list` knows which item is selected, and each `list-item` knows whether its selected. For your simple case one of the other solutions may be more straight-forward, but I find typically with these lists, you'll eventually want more functionality (bind to selected item, more complex templates, etc.).

So one approach may look like this:

```
{{#address-list selected=selectedAddress as |list|}}
  {{#each address in model}}
    {{#address-list-item item=address list=list}}
      <p>{{address.address1}}</p>
    {{/address-list-item}}
  {{/each}}
{{/address-list}}
```

You use block params (note: Ember 1.10 or greater required) to pass the `<address-list>` into each `<address-list-item>`. Now, your address list item can tell the list a new address has been selected, by sending an action to it:

```
App.AddressListItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function() {
    return this.get('list.selected') === this.get('item');
  }.property('list.selected', 'item'),

  click: function() {
    this.get('list').send('select', this.get('item'));
  }
});

App.AddressListComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    select: function(item) {
      this.set('selected', item);
    }
  }
});
```

This sets up all the bindings for you, adds the `.active` class to each `<address-list-item>`, and lets you bind to the `<address-list>`'s selected item from outside the template.

[See a working JSBin here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cakubesuxe/2/edit?html,js,output).

Now, targeting the `list` like this to use `.send` is awkward, which is exactly why soon we'll be able to pass actions down into child components (check out the [Road to Ember 2.0](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) guide and search for "Improving Actions"). Once that functionality lands, you'll be able to pass the `select` action handler from the `<address-list>` directly into each `<address-list-item>`. But this is one way to go, for now, and it'll make refactoring pretty straightforward when those changes do land.

Comment: Im not sure that ALL controllers will go out, just ObjectController and ArrayController, which have the proxying ability (get('foo') can access this.foo or this.model.foo). Correct me please if I'm wrong

Comment: no all controllers are going away, see the Routeable Components section [here](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15) (and the [routeable components RFC](https://github.com/ef4/rfcs/blob/routeable-components/active/0000-routeable-components.md))

Comment: make sure to {{yield this}} in your <address-list> - that's what makes the block param work

Comment: @SamSelikoff I am curious. At your JSBin, what is `yield this` in reference to? Is `this` the entire component object? As in everything including its properties is yielded into `list`? I've read at http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params

Comment: yep this refers to the component itself

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741467/where-should-i-keep-selection-state-for-a-list/14748331#14748331) you could just store a separate list with selected items in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that it is not a real property on your object model, I am assuming you just mean it isn't being persisted. If thats the case, and there is no other use for the flag anywhere other than the current display, the long term solution would be to use a component. See: http://jsbin.com/colacu/1

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [Ember.Object.create({
      address1: 'add1',
      address2: 'add2',
      city: 'Washington'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
      address1: 'add1 again',
      address2: 'add2 again',
      city: 'Seattle'
    })];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  active: null,
  actions: {
    useThisAddress: function(address) {
      address.set('isSelected', true);
      this.set('active', address);
    }
  }
});

App.XAddressComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isSelected: false,
  address: null,
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected'],
  click: function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
    this.sendAction('action', this);
  }
});
```

Template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    Selected: {{selected.value}}
    <ul>
    {{#each model as |item|}}
      {{x-foo value=item action="select"}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/x-foo">
    {{value}}
  </script>
```

But what you have should be just fine.

Comment: Yeap, components are the way to go. But it doesn't feel right trying to set the state of an address item in an ember data model. i.e. `address.set('isSelected', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Just learning Ember myself, but....  my .02.

The list approach is the must un-Emberlike IMO.

The way you are doing it should be fine, assuming you want the isSelected to be quasi-persistant.  It will stay as long as the object stays -- even perhaps between route changes (depending on your model).

If it is supposed to be more transient..   Throw the address into a component and store the isChecked in the component controller.